# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Подскажите, как правильно создать `JSON`-объект?

```
$json=json_encode(array('pattern' => '^(?:/?site/(?[\w\-]+))?(?:/?intl/(?[a-z]{2}(?:\-[a-z]{2})?)/?)?(/?(?.*))'));
JSON.parse(<?php echo $json ?>)
```

**SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В кавычки возьмите

```
$json=json_encode(array('pattern' => '^(?:/?site/(?[\w\-]+))?(?:/?intl/(?[a-z]{2}(?:\-[a-z]{2})?)/?)?(/?(?.*))'));
JSON.parse('<?php echo $json ?>')
```

если уж так делать

Comment: Ошибка осталась JSON.parse: bad escaped character

Comment: Добавил stripslashes и вроде заработало.
'pattern' => stripslashes('.......')